# Spring CSRF not working on Tomcat 7.0.28

Tags: spring, spring-security, tomcat7, csrf-protection

I have a web application which uses Spring Security, version 4.0.1 and Spring version 4.1.6.
In every page of the web app I have the

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"     value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

parameter which sends the CSRF token to the server. Now my problem is that if I see the source code of the jsp I have

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value=""/>
```

so the token is not sent to the server and the post action results in the message **HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported**
If I deploy the same web application on Tomcat 7.0.5.x everything works fine, and it also works fine in WAS 7, WAS 8.5 and Jboss EAP 6.4.
I can not understand why on this version of Tomcat (7.0.28), which I downloaded from the web site without changing anything about configuration etc. , the CSRF protection offered by Spring Security is not working.

Comment: Tomcat 7.0.28? -- you know that the current Tomcat 7 version is  7.0.67!

Comment: Yes I know but one of our client has that version (I have an Internet connection and I am able to write tomcat on google :-)), now I am going to update it but it won't be easy because there are other applications running over there, so we have to guarantee everything will work fine. My aim was to understand what happened

Comment: to be honest, I do not belive that the problem is the tromcat version.

Comment: As I wrote before, upgrading the Tomcat version to the last available solved the problem.

Comment: Of course you are free to believe it is not true ...

Comment: try to use an other tomcat version that is close you one, for example 7.0.29 - it the problem then disappear it is likely that it is a tomcat problem. Maybe you could use this as an argument to update the tomcat instance to an newer oine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem: Tomcat 7.0.28 is not able to auto detect spring security filter.

My solution is to add this :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

to the web.xml and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Open **tomacat/confg** folder
see there is a file **Context.xml** and open it
change **<Context>** to **<Context useHttpOnly="false">**
then you have done.